# Applying for a US visa in Japan with a Japanese visa expiring soon

Tags: visas, usa, japan, visa-expiration

I applied for a US visa from a country other than my own(I am an Indian and I currently work in Japan). My application was put on administrative processing and its been 2 months. I still have no clue as to how long it will take them to process my application. But my Japanese visa will expire soon but I cannot travel to India since my passport is with the US embassy in Tokyo. Can I get my passport back and then submit it at a US embassy in India without affecting my application ?

Comment: You can get your passport back, but this will cancel your application and you'll need to make a new one in India.

Comment: Is it just your visa, or is your approved period of stay (在留期間) also ending?

Comment: My residence permit is valid till next year but my visa is connected to my employment here and as it ends, so does my visa.